# Total risk in multiple risky actions

Tags: probability

I have a minefield with $c \times r$ cells. There are $n$ mines randomly placed in cells (no cell has more than one mine, just none, or one), and $n \lt c \times r$. How do I calculate the risk of exploding at least one mine by probing $m$ distinct cells? Probing does not stop if a mine explodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of ways to select $m$ cells from the minefield is the binomial coefficient ${c r} \choose m$.  The number of ways to select $m$ of the $c r - n$ non-mined cells is ${c r - n} \choose m$.  So if the selection is random, the probability of not finding a mine is ${{c r - n} \choose m}/{{c r} \choose m}$.
The probability of finding at least one mine is $1 - $ that.

Comment: Thanks! From the upvotes I can say your answer is correct, but I have no clue what `${{c r - n} \choose m}/{{c r} \choose m}$` stands for ... is there a way to use simple math functions (+,-,*,/,^) to state the formula?

Comment: Ah, this is the key now: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient